# Issue with the TOP 1 query

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to achieve next thing without using views, but just one single query? I have two tables:

TableA->TanbleB (1-many) ON TableA.Id = TableB.TableAId

I need to update one field in Table A (TableA.Field1) for records in TableA that satisfy condition on one field in tableA (WHERE TableA.Field2=SomeValue)
.
TableA.Field1 will be updated from TableB with value that is last inserted (last inserted value in related records to TableA).

I will put an example:

```
UPDATE TableA a SET Field1 = (SELECT TOP 1 b.Feild1 * b.Field2 FROM TableB b WHERE b.TableAId = a.id) WHERE field2 = 1
```

I know Above example doesn't work, but I have many ways tried using INNER JOIN and failed. I had an idea to use something like this:

```
UPDATE TableA INNDER JOIN ( SELECT ... FROM TABLE B) ON TABLEA.Id= TableB.TableAId SET ....
```

But the 2ns query should return 1 record for each DISTINCT TableAId, but only the last inserted.

I hope I am making some sense here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some SQL that will do what you want

```
UPDATE T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.T1ID SET T1.F2 = [T2].[F2]*[T2].[F3] WHERE (((T1.F1)="ABC") AND ((T2.ID)=DMax("[ID]","[T2]","[T1ID]=" & [T1].[ID])));
```

This predicated on T1.ID being the primary key for T1 and T2.T1ID being a index field in T2

Comment: Ah.. :) I am not sure about DMax if its supported with Access runtime, I couldnt make it run, but it works with normal MAX subquery. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the flaws in Access is that you can't run an "UPDATE" query based on a "SELECT" query, it will usually give the error:

```
Operation must use an updateable query
```

The only way around is as you say to create a view of the "SELECT" query and then inner join this on your table, Access is then working with a static recordset and can handle the "UPDATE" query ok

Alternatively you could write a VBA procedure to step through line by line with the Recordset.

Best of luck : )

UPDATE:

```
SELECT b.TableAId, b.Feild1 * b.Field2 INTO tblView FROM TableB As b WHERE b.field2 = 1
```

Comment: How would you create view in this case? This was my 2nd part of the question.

Comment: @Goran I've added an update on how you could create a static table from your second SQL, note I have added the 'As' keyword before the alias of 'b', this is not required in SQL Server/Oracle but is required in MS Access.

Comment: I am sorry, but we seem to not understand each other. Can you look again at the first query in my post, and write the same query using view. It is of importance that only one query is sent to database (because of network access).

Comment: @Goran What do you mean by 'View', Ms Access does not call it's items 'view' like you would on SQL server, they are saved as 'queries' instead, however as I've explained you can't update from a query in Access and therefore need to have a static table with the records you wish to update, you can then inner join this table in your update query.

Comment: Ok, I will try to explain better the problem: in this case the "static" data for table B is created based on ID from TableA. For each record in TableA, "static" TableB will have only 1 record which is retrieved from this query: [SELECT TOP 1 b.Feild1 * b.Field2 FROM TableB b WHERE b.TableAId = a.id ORDER BY b.id DESC]. Please note the [TOP 1] keyword, since there are many records in TableB that can be joined with TableA on TableA.Id. Are you telling me that I need to send 5000 queries to database, if not, how can I do it otherwise?

Comment: @Goran Ok, in this case then, the second part of my answer is more relevant, you will need to create a VBA procedure that steps through TableA one by one, and executes the second query in a loop.

Comment: But as I already said, I am not using local database, I am using it on network, and the performance is very bad, so this is why I asked the qustion. I am using MS Access only as database, not for application development. Are you 100% sure it can be done in one query?

Comment: @Goran I personally don't think this can be achieved in one query, however as long as you have table access, then you should still be able to write a simple VBA procedure on your deskop, link in the network tables and update in this way.